# Put new data to SQL Server from android volley

Tags: c#, sql-server, android-volley

I want to use android-volley to edit my SQL Server data, I tried to use request method put to update my db, and change data to JSON, and use visual studio to catch JSON, finally change the SQL Server data

**android studio:**

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT,
                    url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {     
                Log.d("success", response);
                Toast.makeText(SystemActivity.this, "succesful!, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("error", error.toString());
            }
        });


        getparams();

        mQueue.add(stringRequest);
        //put-volley

    }

    //put-volley

    protected Map<String, String> getparams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("NotesID", corusername);  //NotesID
        params.put("Password", renewpass);

        return params;
    }
    //put-volley
```

**visual studio:**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(string userID, [FromBody] Account account)
{
    try
    {
        using (DemoEntities entities = new DemoEntities())
        {
            var entity = entities.Account.FirstOrDefault(s => s.NotesID == userID);

            if (entity == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "customers with userid = " + userID + "is not found");
            }
            else
            {
                entity.NotesID = account.NotesID;
                entity.Password = account.Password;

                entities.SaveChanges();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity);
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide some information as to what the error you're seeing is, or what the behavior is that's not working?

Comment: thanks, this is my wrong message, when i click my button, the message will show that
E/Volley: [808] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for "MYURL"
I Log the error message is error: com.android.volley.ClientError

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are calling getParams() outside of StringRequest:

```
getparams(); 
mQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Instead you need to override it in StringRequest scope like:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //Response
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Error
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("NotesID", corusername);  //NotesID
                params.put("Password", renewpass);

                return params;
        }
        @Override
        public HashMap<String, String> getHeaders() {
                HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
        }
};

//Add request to volley request queue
VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

Also HTTP 400 might be because headers Content-Type is set wrong. So you must set headers in StringRequest overriden method like:

```
@Override
public HashMap<String, String> getHeaders() {
        HashMap headers = new HashMap();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return headers;
}
```

Also in order to bind the JSON correctly to your action, you have modified your action to include the attribute [FromBody] on the parameter. So you must define in your request correct headers:

```
contentType:"application/json"
//or
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Also test your PUT request in Postman first.

Comment: I correct my code to your code, and i test my URL and the put code in Postman, i success to change data in my database, but when i back to the android studio, the wrong message is still there
WRONG MESSAGE
E/Volley: [1027] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for "URL"
D/errorrrrrrr: com.android.volley.ClientError

Comment: What do you get in response from Postman request? Also can you show here your headers and body from postman request?

Comment: i put the new password to my url and my sql server database successfully changed the data
Header
key : Content-Type   value : application/json
body
{
 "NotesID" : "A123456789",   // THE ORIGINAL DATA
 "Password" : "1111"   
        // I WROTE THE NEW DATA, IT'S LIKE MY ANDROID STUDIO PUT 
          THE NEW DATA 
}